# Sql table join with no direct relation [ codeigniter ]

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I want to join tables where as `table1` and `table2` are common fields and `table2` contain field `record_id` whos description is in `table3` field `record_desc` what would be query?

There is no direct relation between `table1` and `table3`

I tried like this but won't work.

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table2.record_id= table3.record_desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: are you getting any errors , i think you have different data types for record_desc and record_id , or do they have a same data type , an you update your question with sample tables with data :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line is incorrect

```
$this->db->join('table3', 'table2.record_id= table3.record_desc');
```

because `table3.record_desc` is not the foreign  key from table 2 to table 3 right ?

The query may be like this

```
$this->db->join('table3', 'table2.record_id= table3.record_id');
```

because you have to have a foreign key to match records in table 2 and table 3 .

and when you are selecting the result if you are doing like

```
$this->db->select('*');
```

If you have same column name in each table , only one column will appear in the result .

so try to get only columns you want like this

```
$this->db->select('table1.id,table2.record_id,table3.record_desc');
```

Hope this helps .